# iAd testing ads on real device confusion

Tags: ios-simulator, iad, ios-universal-app, iad-workbench

I want to use test ads on my iPad/iPhone universal app. Do I have to download iAd producer in order to use test ads? With iAd producer I must create my own ads and only those are the ads I can show to users? Or do I have to have a iAd workbench account to launch test ads on my device or is there another way to get test ads for my device and simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do any of those to test ads

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0];

[iAdBanner setAlpha:1];

[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.iAdBanner setDelegate:self];


}



-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{



 [bannerView setDelegate:self];
  [bannerView setAlpha:0];
   bannerView.hidden=YES;

     }
```

Just add the above code and an iAd test banner should appear .

Answer (score 0):

No. iAd producer is for someone who wants to distribute their ads to users. If you are a iOS App Developer, the only thing you need to do is to integrate iAd in your app(with the framework). After you've done that, when you run your app, if you see a banner that shows something like "Welcome to iAd(something about iAd, I don't remember the exact content)", you are done! Before you submit your app to AppStore, remember to go to iTunes Connect to finish your financial contract.